# How to scale up GPU Nodes with autoscaler on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I want to have a instance group that scales from 0 to x pods. I get `Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu`. Does someone see what I'm doing wrong here? This is on Kubernetes v1.9.6 with autoscaler 1.1.2.

I have two instance groups, one with cpus, and a new one I want to scale down to 0 nodes called gpus, so `kops edit ig gpus` is:

```
apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-05-31T09:27:31Z
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster: ci.k8s.local
  name: gpus
spec:
  cloudLabels:
    instancegroup: gpus
    k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled: ""
  image: ami-4450543d
  kubelet:
    featureGates:
      DevicePlugins: "true"
  machineType: p2.xlarge
  maxPrice: "0.5"
  maxSize: 3
  minSize: 0
  nodeLabels:
    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup: gpus
  role: Node
  rootVolumeOptimization: true
  subnets:
  - eu-west-1c
```

And the autoscaler deployment has:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - ./cluster-autoscaler
        - --v=4
        - --stderrthreshold=info
        - --cloud-provider=aws
        - --skip-nodes-with-local-storage=false
        - --nodes=0:3:gpus.ci.k8s.local
        env:
        - name: AWS_REGION
          value: eu-west-1
        image: k8s.gcr.io/cluster-autoscaler:v1.1.2
```

Now I try to deploy a simple GPU test:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: simple-gpu-test
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "simplegputest"
    spec:
      containers: 
      - name: "nvidia-smi-gpu"
        image: "nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn5-runtime"
        resources: 
          limits: 
             nvidia.com/gpu: 1 # requesting 1 GPU
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/local/nvidia
          name: nvidia
        command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
        args: [ "while true; do nvidia-smi; sleep 5; done;" ]
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /usr/local/nvidia
        name: nvidia
```

I expect the instance group to go from 0 to 1, but the autoscaler logs show:

```
I0605 11:27:29.865576       1 scale_up.go:54] Pod default/simple-gpu-test-6f48d9555d-l9822 is unschedulable
I0605 11:27:29.961051       1 scale_up.go:86] Upcoming 0 nodes
I0605 11:27:30.005163       1 scale_up.go:146] Scale-up predicate failed: PodFitsResources predicate mismatch, cannot put default/simple-gpu-test-6f48d9555d-l9822 on template-node-for-gpus.ci.k8s.local-5829202798403814789, reason: Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu
I0605 11:27:30.005262       1 scale_up.go:175] No pod can fit to gpus.ci.k8s.local
I0605 11:27:30.005324       1 scale_up.go:180] No expansion options
I0605 11:27:30.005393       1 static_autoscaler.go:299] Calculating unneeded nodes
I0605 11:27:30.008919       1 factory.go:33] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"simple-gpu-test-6f48d9555d-l9822", UID:"3416d787-68b3-11e8-8e8f-0639a6e973b0", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"12429157", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)
I0605 11:27:30.031707       1 leaderelection.go:199] successfully renewed lease kube-system/cluster-autoscaler
```

When I start a node by setting the minimum tot 1, I see that it has the capacity:

```
Capacity:
 cpu:             4
 memory:          62884036Ki
 nvidia.com/gpu:  1
 pods:            110

and labels
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=p2.xlarge
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-1c
                    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup=gpus
                    kubernetes.io/role=node
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/node=
                    spot=true
```

The required tag is present on the AWS Scale group:

```
{
    "ResourceId": "gpus.ci.k8s.local",
    "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
    "Key": "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/node-template/label/kops.k8s.io/instancegroup",
    "Value": "gpus",
    "PropagateAtLaunch": true
}
```

Finally, when I set the min pool size to 1, it can scale from 1 to 3 automatically. Just doesn't do 0 to 1.

Is there someway I can perhaps inspect the template to see why it doesn't have the resource?

Comment: Is there some way I can inspect the template?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue

Comment: Yes, it works for me now. The tags did not match, which Autoscaler needs to match a launch configuration to a node group. By adding both the taint and label to the launch configuration in AWS, autoscaler can now find the correct group. The docs have been updated with better examples as well now. If you follow those, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md)
is a standalone program that adjusts the size of a Kubernetes cluster to meet the current needs.
Cluster Autoscaler can manage GPU resources provided by the cloud provider in the same manner.

Based on cluster [autoscaler documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-can-i-scale-a-node-group-to-0),
for AWS, it is possible to scale a node group to 0 (and obviously from 0), assuming that all scale-down conditions are met.

Going back to your question, for AWS, if you are using nodeSelector, you need to tag your nodes in the ASG template using labels like "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/node-template/label/". 
Please note that Kubernetes and AWS GPU support require different labels.

For example, for a node label of foo=bar, you would tag the ASG with:

```
{
    "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
    "ResourceId": "foo.example.com",
    "PropagateAtLaunch": true,
    "Value": "bar",
    "Key": "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/node-template/label/foo"
}
```

Comment: I added the label gpu-group=true to the node, and the scaling group has

    {
        "ResourceId": "gpus.ci.k8s.local",
        "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
        "Key": "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/node-template/label/gpu-group",
        "Value": "true",
        "PropagateAtLaunch": true
}.

Yet I keep the same error.

Comment: Also, it should already match on kops.k8s.io/instancegroup=gpus

Comment: If you followed everything above and it still doesn't work for you, check autoscaler pod logs. For some reason my pod got stuck and had to restart it to make the config changes to work

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to have a non-zero limit for the desired instance types in the AWS account.